# How to provide a different id for each component creating a button is called

Tags: javascript, input, reactjs

So the problem is that I can't manage to provide a unique `id` for the buttons I created. My current code to provide the `id` is to increment a `count` variable every time I call the component and then assign it to the button, but the `id` of all buttons always end up with the current count. I will use the `id` as a base to delete a specific element in the array. Any other methods will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the component that creates the button:

```
class TodoListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    this.arrTodos = this.props.todos;
  }
  onDelete(e) {
    let btnDel = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.btnDel);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li>
          {this.props.desc}
          <span>    </span>
          <input ref="btnDel" type='submit' id={this.props.btnID} value='Delete' onClick={this.onDelete} />
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the main class:

```
class Todolist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      btnID: -1
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.createTodo = this.createTodo.bind(this);
    this.todos = {};
    this.todoID = 0;
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    let value = this.refs.myInput.value;
    let myInput = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput);
    if (value == "") {
      myInput.focus();
      return;
    } else {
      let newTodo = {
        idTodo: this.todoID,
        desc: value,
        done: false
      };
      this.todos = newTodo;
      this.setState({
        todos:[...this.state.todos,newTodo],
        btnID: this.state.btnID + 1
      });
      myInput.value = "";
      myInput.focus();
      this.todoID++;
    }
  }
  onInput(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  }
  createTodo(todo) {
    return <TodoListItem key={todo.idTodo} todos={this.state.todos} desc={todo.desc} btnID={this.state.btnID} />
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input ref="myInput" placeholder="What To Do?" />
        <input type="submit" onClick = {this.onSubmit} />
        <ul>{this.state.todos.map(this.createTodo)} </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Side note: Please check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296391/should-phrases-such-as-i-am-new-to-x-be-edited-out-of-questions on whether adding random greetings is good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than pass the todo's ID, I would be tempted to pass a remove method as a prop, with the todo already bound in place.

```
removeTodo: function(target) {
  const { todos } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    todos: todos.filter(todo => todo !== target)
  });
}
```

Then you can partially apply a version of the function to pass to the component.

```
createTodo(todo) {
  const remove = this.removeTodo.bind(this, todo);

  return <TodoListItem key={todo.idTodo} todos={this.state.todos} desc={todo.desc} remove={remove} />
}
```

Then inside your component, you can simply call the remove function when you want to delete it.

```
<input type='submit' value='Delete' onClick={this.props.remove} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D, and because of your answer, i have learned that methods can also be passed as props,i thought values are the only one that can be passed XD

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you need the id for, but when you do your `map` just pass the iterator as well, so you would have something like

```
this.state.todos.map(function(todo, i){
  this.createTodo(todo, i);
}.bind(this));
```

Then within your `createTodo` you can just use `i` as your `key` and your `id`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D